Timefold SolverFactory.create() - Invalid function: expected 2 arguments but got 1
I'm working with the Timefold Solver and encountering the following error when trying to create a SolverFactory:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"G:\PycharmProject\Timefold-training\tools\main.py", line 62, in

solver_factory = SolverFactory.create(   File "G:\PycharmProject\Timefold-training\venv\lib\site-packages\timefold\solver_solver_factory.py",
line 52, in create
delegate = JavaSolverFactory.create(solver_config)  # noqa ValueError: Invalid function: expected 2 arguments but got 1

Here's the relevant code where the error occurs:
solver_factory = SolverFactory.create(
    SolverConfig(
        solution_class=DeviceSchedule,
        entity_class_list=[Device],
        score_director_factory_config=ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig(
            constraint_provider_function=define_constraints
        ),
        termination_config=TerminationConfig(
            spent_limit=Duration(seconds=60)
        )
    )
)

I have the following domain classes:
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Annotated, Set, List
from timefold.solver.domain import PlanningId, planning_entity, planning_solution, PlanningVariable, \
    PlanningEntityCollectionProperty, ProblemFactCollectionProperty, ValueRangeProvider, PlanningScore
from timefold.solver.score import HardSoftScore

@dataclass
class Technician:
    id: Annotated[int, PlanningId]
    name: str
    rbh_do_zaplanowania: float
    rbh_przydzielone: float
    iums: Set[str]

    def has_ium(self, ium: str) -> bool:
        return ium in self.iums

@dataclass
class Device:
    index: Annotated[int, PlanningId]
    ium: str
    nazwa: str
    typ: str
    nr_fabryczny: str
    rbh_norma: float
    dni_w_om: int
    uzytkownik: str
    technician: Annotated[Technician | None, PlanningVariable(allows_unassigned=True)] = field(default=None)

@dataclass
@planning_solution
class DeviceSchedule:
    id: str
    technician_list: Annotated[List[Technician], ProblemFactCollectionProperty, ValueRangeProvider]
    device_list: Annotated[List[Device], PlanningEntityCollectionProperty]
    score: Annotated[HardSoftScore, PlanningScore] = field(default=None)

And this is my constraints.py file:
from timefold.solver.score import constraint_provider, HardSoftScore, ConstraintFactory

@constraint_provider
def define_constraints(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return [
        technician_capacity_hard(constraint_factory),
        technician_skill_conflict(constraint_factory),
    ]

def technician_skill_conflict(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(Device)
        .filter(lambda device: device.technician is not None and not device.technician.has_ium(device.ium))
        .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
        .as_constraint("Technician skill conflict")
    )

def technician_capacity_hard(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(Device)
        .group_by(lambda device: device.technician, sum(lambda device: device.rbh_norma))
        .filter(lambda technician, total_rbh_norma: total_rbh_norma > technician.rbh_do_zaplanowania)
        .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD, lambda technician, total_rbh_norma: total_rbh_norma - technician.rbh_do_zaplanowania)
        .as_constraint("Technician capacity")
    )

I suspect the issue might have to do with how I'm using SolverFactory.create() or my configuration, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. I’ve reviewed the Timefold Solver documentation, but I can't pinpoint the cause of this error.
Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone know what might be going wrong?

The issue is in technician_capacity_hard; you need to use ConstraintCollectors.sum instead of builtins.sum. This code should work:
from timefold.solver.score import ConstraintCollectors

def technician_capacity_hard(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(Device)
        .group_by(lambda device: device.technician, ConstraintCollectors.sum(lambda device: device.rbh_norma))
        .filter(lambda technician, total_rbh_norma: total_rbh_norma > technician.rbh_do_zaplanowania)
        .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD, lambda technician, total_rbh_norma: total_rbh_norma - technician.rbh_do_zaplanowania)
        .as_constraint("Technician capacity")
    )


Thank You for the answer it solves the problem :). I hope in the future there will be  better timefold documentation fot the python because huge community of machine learning engineers works with python not with java.
